# Get page url using javascript

Tags: javascript

Could someone recommend a way to get page name from a url using JavaScript?

For instance if I have:

```
http://www.cnn.com/news/1234/news.html?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

I just need to get "news.html" string

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily via `window.location.pathname` parsing:

```
var file, n;

file = window.location.pathname;
n = file.lastIndexOf('/');
if (n >= 0) {
    file = file.substring(n + 1);
}
alert(file);
```

...or as others have said, you can do it with a regexp in one line. One kinda dense-looking line, but with a comment above it, should be a good way to go.

Comment: +1  I'm impressed with the power of regex, but I can't read 'em.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's

```
window.location.pathname.replace(/^.*\/([^/]*)/, "$1");
```

So,

```
var pageTitle = window.location.pathname.replace(/^.*\/([^/]*)/, "$1");
```

Comment: I think you need to escape forward slashes there. :)

Comment: Nice! I never knew about `pathname`!

Comment: Don't you want a `$` at the end of that? To avoid partial matches?

Comment: Answering myself: Not in my experiments, no.

Comment: I figured the * would eat up the rest of the pathname string, which I think is what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 3):

```
var url = "http://www.cnn.com/news/1234/news.html?a=1&b=2&c=3";
url = url.replace(/^.*\//, "").replace(/\?.*$/, "");
```

You can substitute `url` with `window.location`

Comment: As a note, doing window.location.replace(/^.*\//, "").replace(/\?.*$/, ""); will redirect you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to also find file paths on a local disk,
and you might not want to include any hash or get strings in the path-

```
String.prototype.fileName= function(){
 var f, s= this.split(/[#\?]/, 1)[0].replace(/\\/g,'/');
 s= s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('/')+ 1);
 f=  /^(([^\.]+)(\.\w+)?)/.exec(s) || [];
 return f[1] ||  '';
}
```