# how can I get asp.net aspx page name from javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Trying to get the aspx name from the current page from javascript?

Comment: Pretty much what you need here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426958/get-page-url-using-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
<script language="javascript">  
        var url = window.location.pathname;  
        var myPageName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);      
        alert(myPageName);  
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative -

```
var page = '<%=Path.GetFileName(Request.Path)%>'
```

Do you want to parse the current window, or rely on asp.net?
Both work - it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

To Get The Exact Formname using jquery one can do string manipulation as shown.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var page = path.substr( path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1 ).split(".",1);
    var formname=page[0].toString();
    alert(formname);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This one without the query string

```
$(function () {
    var url = window.location.pathname;  
    var pageQuery = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var page = pageQuery.split('?')[0];
)}
```