# best way to tie unique local storage to a unique web page on a domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, uniqueidentifier

I have a javascript engine that creates a 'magazine' out of a typical web page. Several web pages would have separate 'issues', all using the same javascript engine that drives the formatting and behaviour.

The engine uses local storage to remember which 'page' of the issue the user was on when they last read the issue of the magazine.

```
localStorage.setItem('currentPage',JSON.stringify(currentPage));
var currentPage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentPage'));
var remover = $('.article-wrapper:eq(' + currentPage + ')');
```

my problem is, if I visit page 5 of a magazine titled 'autumn', close it and open a magazine titled 'spring', then I will start on page 5 of spring automatically.

Is there a way I can set a unique 'currentPage' variable name for each issue in the html for that issue, read it with the javascript for the engine and then have it save to local storage for the computer/device the user is using?

You can test the problem by visiting these two sites. Open both. Go to page five of one site and then refresh the other. It will change to the others page number.

http://straathof.acadnet.ca/autumn/

http://straathof.acadnet.ca/portfolio/

Answer (score 3):

Instead of storing the `currentPage` as a simple integer, store an object that keeps track of both the current page's url and the page for that url.

For example:

```
// When saving the current page.
var currentPage = new Object();
var url = window.location.pathname;
currentPage[url] = 9;
localStorage.setItem('currentPage', JSON.stringify(currentPage));

// When loading the current page.
var currentPage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentPage'));
var remove = $('.article-wrapper:eq(' + currentPage[url] + ')');
```

If you do not like having the full URL as the key, then you could use `indexOf` to find the pages name. See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426958/get-page-url-using-javascript) for more.

Comment: Thank you, @BrantOlsen. Unfortunately the pages are not web pages per se. The entire 'issue' of said magazine is one 'web page'. Each article, one of which is defined as 'current page', stored numerically, is the visible part of that web page.

Comment: Think of them as the information one sees when one clicks a tab or 'next/prev' button in a carousel. It's highly modified so the information takes over the entire screen.

Comment: The problem itself is compounded by the fact that storing the currentpage variable means that any web page in the domain will have the same value. So in the case I gave above, if you visit article '5' of the autumn 'issue' you will automatically start on article '5' when you open the portfolio 'issue'.

Comment: I've removed the ability to 'store' your last visited 'page' number because, if the issues have different number of pages, and you are past the value of the highest page in the next visited issue, you are granted with a blank page, since you are effectively outside the range of pages. Storing where you were when you closed the issue was a nice idea, but the practicality of doing so was rather awkward to implement.

Comment: All I needed was a way to identify 'currentpage' as a variable name specific to each 'issue' without resorting to changing the javascript code for each implementation of the publishing engine. Thank you very much for the answer, though. I really do appreciate it.